# Conditionally enable Wildfly json-formatter on startup depending on environment variable

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'd like to enable WildFly's `json-formatter` for logging depending on the value of an environment variable when the server starts.

The following CLI commands work fine when the server is already started and I connect to it via `jboss-cli.sh`. But how could I control whether this configuration is active or not when starting the server?

```
if (result == "true") of :resolve-expression(expression=${env.JSON_FORMATTER_ENABLED})
    /subsystem=logging/json-formatter=JSON:add(pretty-print=false, exception-output-type=formatted)
    /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=named-formatter, value="JSON")
end-if
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to only use the `json-formatter` if an environment variable is set?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but at least it's the best solution I could come up with. It seems to do the job, but I guess there are more elegant solutions.

I add a second `console-handler` which uses the `json-formatter`:

```
# add separate console-handler with json-formatter
/subsystem=logging/json-formatter=JSON:add(pretty-print=false, exception-output-type=formatted)
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE-JSON:add(named-formatter="JSON", level=INFO)
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:add-handler(name=CONSOLE-JSON)
```

Then, depending on an environment variable, I enable/disable the respective `console-handler` as it seems to be the only WildFly resource which supports expressions:

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE-JSON:write-attribute(name=enabled, value="${env.JSON_CONSOLE_HANDLER_ENABLED}"
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=enabled, value="${env.DEFAULT_CONSOLE_HANDLER_ENABLED}"
```

And finally, in my Docker startup script `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```
if [ "${JSON_FORMATTER_ENABLED}" == "true" ]; then
  export JSON_CONSOLE_HANDLER_ENABLED="true"
  export DEFAULT_CONSOLE_HANDLER_ENABLED="false"
else
  export JSON_CONSOLE_HANDLER_ENABLED="false"
  export DEFAULT_CONSOLE_HANDLER_ENABLED="true"
fi
```